# Exception when trying to populate table view controller with the data retrieved from sql + NSRangeException'

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios6

I am new to iOS development and i face weird problem (cuz the same code in both table view controller and sql class works pretty good with other entity).

I am trying to **retrive the data from sqlite database to my table view controller**..

and this error shows up **when i try to insert more than one record in the database.**
2012-11-10 19:04:20.577 my app[7032:11303] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:

Any help will be appreciated.
**Thank you.**

---

```
import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
import "Category.h"
import "DbOperations.h"
import "AddCategoriesTVC.h"
import "CategoryDetailTVC.h"@interface CategoriesTVC : UITableViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate,AddCategoriesTVCDelegate, CategoryDetailTVCDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) Category *categoryItem;
@property(nonatomic, strong) DbOperations * ops;
@property(nonatomic, strong) NSMutableArray * myCategoryArray;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView * categoryTable;
@end
///////////
import "CategoriesTVC.h"
import "Category.h"
import "DbOperations.h"
import "sqlite3.h"
@implementation CategoriesTVC
@synthesize categoryTable;
@synthesize categoryItem,myCategoryArray,ops;

- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewStyle)style
{
self = [super initWithStyle:style];
if (self) {
    // Custom initialization
}
return self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
// Releases the view if it doesn't have a superview.
[super didReceiveMemoryWarning];

// Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

- (void)viewDidLoad
{ops = [[DbOperations alloc]init];
[ops selectCategories];
myCategoryArray = [ops categoryArray];
self.editButtonItem.title = @"edit";
self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
[super viewDidLoad];
}


- (void)viewDidUnload
{
[self setCategoryTable:nil];
[super viewDidUnload];
}

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{[super viewWillAppear:animated];
//myCategoryArray =[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];//]
[ops selectCategories];
myCategoryArray = [ops categoryArray];
[categoryTable reloadData];}

//pragma mark - Table view data source
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
// Return the number of sections.
return 1;}


- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
 NSLog(@"JJJJ2");
// Return the number of rows in the section.
return [self.myCategoryArray count];}


- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Category Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

Category * categoryObj = [ops.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = categoryObj.categoryName;
cell.textLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;//UITextAlignmentCenter;

return cell;}
```

---

```
@interface DbOperations : NSObject
{
sqlite3 * db;
}
//to add the contents of the database which will be the data source for the table
@property(nonatomic,strong)NSMutableArray * categoryArray;

//instance methods for ** Category Entity **

-(void) selectCategories;
-(void) insertCategory:(NSString *)categoryName;
-(void) updateCategory:(NSString *)categoryName:(NSString *)categoryName2;
-(void) deleteCategory:(NSString *)categoryName;
------------------------------------------
------------------------------------------
-(void) selectCategories{

categoryArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
//Get list of directories in Document path
NSArray * dirPath = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);

//Define new path for database
NSString * documentPath = [[dirPath objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"SmartSpeakerDB.sqlite"];
//By default there should only have one item in the array, so the index is always 0 unless you add subdirectories.

if(!(sqlite3_open([documentPath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK))
{
    NSLog(@"An error has occured.");

    return;
}else{//e2


    const char *sql = "SELECT categoryName FROM Category";
    //const char * sql, will be execute the SELECT statement.
    sqlite3_stmt *sqlStatement;


    if(sqlite3_prepare_v2(db, sql, -1, &sqlStatement, NULL) != SQLITE_OK)
    {
        NSLog(@"There is a problem with prepare statement Hah");
        return;
    }else{
        while (sqlite3_step(sqlStatement)==SQLITE_ROW) {
             NSLog (@"ENTER while");

 char * checkChar = (char*)sqlite3_column_text(sqlStatement,0);//1
    if (checkChar!= NULL) {
        NSString *s=[NSString stringWithUTF8String:checkChar];
                Category * newCategory = [[Category alloc] init];
        newCategory.categoryName = s;

             NSLog (@"***");
                [categoryArray addObject:newCategory];
            NSLog(@"Name %@",newCategory.categoryName);
               newCategory = nil;

     }//END IF
        }//END While
        sqlite3_finalize(sqlStatement);
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }//END ELSE 1
}//END ELSE 2
}//End
```

Comment: Your edited question still doesn't point out which line of code is causing the exception.

Answer (score 0):

I looks like it is probably because you are using:

```
[self.myCategoryArray count];
```

in `numberOfRowsInSection` but:

```
[ops.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.

If the two arrays have different numbers of objects, then you will have this problem.  You typically use the same array for both functions so that this can't happen.

Answer (score 0):

You don't state where in all of that code you are actually having the problem but I see one likely issue. In your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method you return:

```
[self.myCategoryArray count];
```

But then in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method you call:

```
Category * categoryObj = [ops.categoryArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

You are using two different arrays here. These should be based on the same data.

For future reference, when posting these type of questions, point out the exact line the exception is coming from and only post relevant code.

Comment: the problem is when i try to insert **more than one** record in the database. i want to ask if you mean that these two arrays having different data. and thank you so much.

Comment: I'm not sure what you just said. The data source for a table view should come from one set of data. You are using two different arrays here. They need to be the same arrays. If `self.myCategoryArray` has 10 objects, for example, then the table view will ask for 10 cells. If `ops.categoryArray` has less than 10 objects, it will crash. Use the same array for both methods.

Comment: sorry for bothering you .. but in view did loud the 2 statement here says that these two array have the same data is that correct?[ops selectCategories];
myCategoryArray = [ops categoryArray];.. and i used the same array for both methods and the problem still there. i know i ask a lot but how can i know which line of code arrise this problem .. thank you so much..

Comment: Run the app with the debugger. When it crashes, the debugger will show a stack trace showing the exact path of code. Start at the top of the stack trace and find the first reference to your own code. That is where it is crashing in your code. I now see that the two arrays are the same. That's confusing. And referencing the two arrays in the two different data source methods is even more confusing. Use one or the other.